# How to handle caller id when using Asterisk ARI external to external

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

Right now, I'm making outgoing calls using Asterisk ARI from my mobile number to another mobile number, using the below request:

```
endpoint=PJSIP/mynumber&extension=1**other_number&context=from-internal&priority=1&timeout=30
```

In this situation, I would like to display the custom caller id number, when calling other number. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your callerid number as Query paramter.
add,

```
callerId=987654321
```

if you want to display caller id name also,

```
callerId=<User 1>987654321
```

*Note the it is "I" (callerId) and not "i" (callerid) in the parameter name.

Comment: This is the only post on the world wide web that answers how to add both name and number. Only thing, I found it to be the other way around as `name<number>`. Also you gotta encode the space as `%20`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more query string callerId. It will be like `&callerId=1234567890`.